# Do I need to collect luggage if transiting through São Paulo from Johannesburg to Lima?

Tags: transit, luggage, international-travel, gru

I am flying via São Paulo to Lima, departing from Johannesburg. My layover in Sao is now over 12 hours due to an airline schedule change. I want to book the transit hotel, but am not sure if my checked baggage will need to be collected at GRU.

Answer (score 1):

- If your flight is booked on a single ticket your bags are typically checked through to your final destination
- If you have a long layover, you can request your bags to be unloaded in Sao Paulo. Most airlines (but not all) will do this but policies vary and you need to check directly with your airline and your specific booking.
- If it's two separate tickets, you will have to collect your bags anyway.
- In these cases it's typically best to put your transfer necessities in your carry on. Collecting, carrying and re-checking bags is a lot of work. If all you need is a toothbrush and fresh pair undies, it will easily fit in a small carry on bag.